# how can I ensure traffic is being served only on my new cloud run service deployment?

Tags: google-cloud-run

I am seeing in my stackdriver logs that I am running an old revision of a cloud run service, while the console shows only one newer revision as live.

In this case I have a cloud run container built in a GCP project, but which is deployed in a second project, using the fully specified image name.  (My attempts at Terraform were sidetracked into an auth catch 22, so until I have restored determination, I am manually deploying.)  I don't know if this wrinkle of the two projects is relevant to my question.  Otherwise all the auth works.

In brief, why may I be seeing old deployments receiving traffic minutes after the new deployment is made? Even more than 30 minutes later traffic is still reaching the old deployment.

Comment: One thing I _can_ do is to erase the prior GCR images, and hope that there's no too-clever caching to trip me up.

Comment: It seems removing the GCR images did *not* prevent new invocations from being handled by an old "missing" image.

Comment: Do you use tags or traffic splitting? How do you deploy your new revision?

Comment: I have been copying the build artifact image name with long SHA, and pasting into the deploy new version (with the flag to switch over all traffic).

Comment: I am going to see if the strange behavior goes away if I do one less strange thing.  I'll try to trigger the build in the same project as that in which it will be deployed.

Comment: Do you talk about Cloud Run managed? And do you only see the old revision in Stackdriver without no new request served or do you really have traffic served to the old revision?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things to take into account here:

1. Try explicitly telling Cloud Run to [migrate all traffic to the latest](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/rollouts-rollbacks-traffic-migration#send-to-latest) revision. You can do that by adding the following to your .yaml file

```
metadata:
 name: SERVICE
spec:
...
  traffic:
  - latestRevision: true
    percent: 100
```

2. Try always adding `:latest` tag upon the building of a new image
   so instead of only having let's say gcr.io/project/newimage it would be gcr.io/project/newimage:latest. This way you will ensure the latest image is being used and not previously automatically assigned tags.

If neither fix your issue, then please provide the logs as there might be something useful that indicates what is the root cause. (Also let us know if you are using any caching config)

Comment: Your point #2 about using `:latest` tag in the image is incorrect. Cloud Run does not re-download images based on their tags. It resolves their sha256 hash at the time of deployment, and pulls via that immutable reference.

Comment: I am using a dockerfile, not a .yaml.  Is this the latestRevision flag the same as setting the traffic flag in the console's cloud run deployment page?

Comment: Yes, I see the generated yaml has:
```
traffic:
  - percent: 100
    latestRevision: true
```

Comment: @AhmetB-Google I only recommended this as I was not sure if the image was used from somewhere else as well. But you are right, for cloud run it should not make any difference.

mohawkTrail Could you please update the question and provide the Dockerfile, logs and any other relevant info ?

Answer (score 2):

You can tell Cloud Run to route all traffic to the latest instance with `gcloud run services update-traffic [SERVICE NAME] --to-latest`. That will route all traffic to the latest deployment, and update the traffic allocation as you deploy new instances.

You might not want to use this if you need to validate the service after deployment and before "opening the floodgates", or if you're doing canary deployments.